# How to solve $n>8 \log n$?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

For $n\in \mathbb{N},  $ I need to solve the inequality $n > 8 \log n$, where log is the natural logarithm. To my surprise I could not solve it analytically. Here is an attempt to solve it:

$$\frac {n}{\log n}> 8 \implies \log n^\frac{1}{n} > \frac {1}{8} \implies n ^{\frac {1}{n}} >e^{\frac {1}{8}}.$$

But this is not allowing for resolving after $n.$

Can somebody help me find a way out of this ?  It can be probably solved numerically, but I do not have the background for that.

Comment: To solve this, you need the Lambert-W-function or numerical methods. There is no analytic way to solve this. Google "bisection method" or "newton method". It is not too difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post an answer on that, or at least give me some tipps for using that function ?

Comment: Basically, the Lambert-W-function is the inverse of the function $f(x)=x\cdot e^x$. I am not sure how to apply this on this equation. Maybe, Wolfram Alpha helps.

Comment: @Peter $n$ is an integer!

Comment: @almagest You mean, we need no numerical methods because we can find the point where $8$ is exceeded by enumeration ? Well, that is a point.

Comment: @Peter More generally I meant that we do not need the **exact** point at which the (real) curves cross, so Lambert-W is overkill.

Comment: Lambert-W: $e^{n/8}>n\iff -\frac18<-\frac{n}8e^{-n/8}\iff W_0(-\frac18)<-\frac{n}8\lor W_{-1}(-\frac18)>-\frac{n}8$, giving boundaries $n<1.15537082510...$ or $n>26.09348547661...$

Comment: @almagest In this case, I agree , because the point is at a small position. But if the point would be, lets say, a $13$-digit number, enumeration would be the overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$26/\ln 26 = 7.98 \dotsm$, $27/ \ln 27 = 8.19\dotsm$. Thus the answer is $n \geqslant 27$.

Comment: The argument is not quite complete. The function $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ has a local minimum at $x=e$. So, we must consider the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ as well.

Comment: The inequality also holds for $n=1$.